# How do I use react-hook-form when mapping?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

So I am using React and Material UI. Basically, in my state I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{ title: string, url: string, id: string },...];
```

On my page I want the user to be able to edit these so I've set up the page like so:

```
 const links = useSelector((state: RootState) => { state.links });
 const onEdit = (data: { title: string, url: string }) => console.log(data);

 {links.map((link) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onEdit)} key={link.id}>
      <Grid container >

        <Grid item xs={5}>
          <TextField
            name="title"
            defaultValue={link.title}
            type="text"
            inputRef={register({
              required: {
                value: true,
              },
            })}
          />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={5}>
          <TextField
            name="url"
            defaultValue={link.url}
            type="url"
            variant="outlined"
            inputRef={register({
              required: {
                value: true,
              },
            })}
          />
        </Grid>

        <Button
          className={styles.button}
          type="submit"
          data-testid="submit-button">
          Edit
        </Button>

        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            onDelete(link.id);
          }}
          data-testid="delete-button">
          Delete
        </Button>

      </Grid>
    </form>
  ))}
```

So let's say I have the following in my state:

```
[{ title: 'google', url: 'google.com', id: '123' }, { title: 'YouTube', url: 'YouTube', id: '456' }, { title: 'Facebook', url: 'Facebook', id: '789' }]
```

The react component will render the values of these into the textfields and the user can directly change it and click edit to update the state.

The problem is when I try to click the edit button for any of the forms rendered, it always consoles `{ title: 'Facebook', url: 'Facebook' }` whereas I want it to console the values depending on which form's edit button is clicked.

Hopefully that was clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As understood on edit you just need to display the specific items title and url in the console and you have the item ie. link

As in onDelete link.id is been passed similarly onEdit link object can be passed onEdit(link)

```
const onEdit = (data) => console.log(data);
```